# How do Wi-Fi networks persist between installs?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I've just done a reinstall from the recovery partition and have found that all the previously known Wi-Fi networks have persisted, even though I formatted the main partition during the reinstall.

How are they still here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are synchronised over iCloud, so if you log in to iCloud the list of networks and their associated passwords are added to macOS.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks for the (incredibly) speedy reply!

Comment: If you have an iDevice, they'll also by synced across devices. E.g. my iPad automatically logs into all networks I have previously logged into with my laptop.